# I added Keychain support for my mobile app in Entitlement plist But unable to prepare release build in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I added Keychain support for my mobile app in Entitlement plist But unable to prepare release build in xamarin

Below is the error I am facing after I add Entitlement into iOS Project Properties

> Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ValuD.MobilD.IWMS.iOS/251d0141d24521bb61666d94057028a9/bin/iPhone/Release/ProjectNamespace.app' on the device 'iPhone 6s Plus': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile.

Please Find Attached screenshots for more help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the App Groups in the Developer website for the app id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**

### Put lots of efforts on this bug and finally solved it ;) .. Guys Sharing my answer, which is 100 % working ... Trust me you will find it very helpful.

**

**Whenever you need Entitlement plist to be added as part of your build it must be provided in custom entitlement section, you will find it in iOS project properties where we select the Provisioning Profile.**

To find appropriate Entitlement Plist for your provisioning profile just follow below steps and done:-

1. Download the provision profile by login to your developer.apple.com portal
2. Open the provision profile in edit text (MAC) or notepad (windows) and Find for key Entitlements
3. Below to above TAG you will find Entitlement Plist code is enclosed in  TAG as mentioned in below example:-
4. Ex :- `<dict> <key> keychain-access-groups </key> <array> </dict>`
5. Copy and replace the  TAG code to your plist
6. Done

Enjoy ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the provisioning profile services enabled for the app id

Comment: I have checked the same and configured correctly probably..,

Comment: To keep sensitive data in mobile keychain I enable the keychain services in Entitlement plist ,
facing this issue after adding Keychain for my app ...
Before it was working fine for me